# Python3 - how to add attributes to a module, before it executes?

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

Application: imagine financial analysts, quickly writing snippets of Python code, and being able to use handy financial functions and shared variables, without having to do any imports, define functions, or do anything. Just a flat source file of the code they want to write, and nothing else.

I can almost get there, by dynamically loading a source file as module (easy), and adding my functions+variables as attributes to the loaded module (even easier). The problem is that loading a module causes the module to execute, which is too soon. Undefined functions, etc.

Python 3.x and PEP 402 introduce Module Specs, and the `create_module` and `exec_module` functions. Create the module, add attributes, and then execute. Perfect. Except `create_module` is allowed to return `None`. And browsing the 3.5 `importlib.abc`, `.util`, and `.machinery` code, all implementations of `create_module` return `None`.

So I am wondering if I instead have to write my own loader, and/or importer, and/or something else. Btw I favor adding to a module, rather than adding to `builtins`, but if `builtins` works and is my only option I'll do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like fractally bad code design. One namespace, sounds like PHP.......... But to be fair to PHP, PHP now has namespaces.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I have absolutely no interest in design opinions. 

If you have anything pertinent to contribute, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: You could follow the design pattern in this module and just remove the try/except block. It's a full Python parser that overrides globals().

You could just add in a while loop to wait until a custom `exec` signal is sent to then avoid leaving the `__call__`. I know the name of the module is crude, but it's actually a good example of implementing your own Python parser using ast and compile.

https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy/blob/master/fuckit.py

Comment: Thanks ... that looks like a really interesting module to study (though I agree the name is a little crude; not my favorite).

Someone on #python tipped me off to exec(), which lets execute a module and pass in globals as well, and that might be all I need. But I'm bookmarking f****.py to have a look at.

Comment: If you're seriously interested, I would also take a look at the source for Pythran, Nuikta, and the AST module (disclaimer: I've used both, but have no affiliation with either):

https://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2013/pdfs/guelton.pdf
https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/pythran/tree/master/pythran
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html
https://github.com/kayhayen/Nuitka/blob/1eed85366a5dcfd3bbad5e284229e2be671ede1a/nuitka/tree/Helpers.py

Pythran and Nuitka custom-compile Python code from exported classes to C++, allowing you to see how to write a good Python parser.

Comment: Those do sound interesting ... I don't currently have a requirement to parse Python but that could change.

Comment: Btw it looks like `exec()` does not quite do the trick. I'd like to be able to access any globals created in the user's code, and I don't get that with `exec()`, which simply runs the user's code (`exec()` returns `None`). So I am still looking for an approach which loads the user's code as a module.